# Create JTable rendering method which can be called by another class

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JFrame which has a JTable and it can represent data from database. Everything is fine but I want to load or refresh it from another class after a delete operation.

I have already done the delete operation but I can not load the JTable from another class. My code is below:

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

DefaultTableModel model=null;
try {
    model = makeTableModel();
} catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
table = new JTable(model);
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        String getvalue = (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
        PopulatePhotographerClass pp=new PopulatePhotographerClass(getvalue);
    }
});
table.setRowHeight(200);

scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

Here is my `makeTableModel` method:

```
public static DefaultTableModel makeTableModel() throws SQLException, IOException {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Image", "Name","Address","mobile-Number","NID"}, 0) {
         @Override
         public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
             return columnIndex == 0 ? Icon.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
         }

     };
     String cmd = "select * from photographer_lookup";
     try (Connection con =database.DbConnect.getconnection()) {
     try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(cmd)) {
     try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
         while (rs.next()) {
             String name = rs.getString(3);
             Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
             String address=rs.getString("address");
             String mobile=rs.getString("mobile_number");
             String nid=rs.getString("Nid");
             ImageIcon icon = null;
             try (InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream()) {
                 BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
                 icon = new ImageIcon(img);
             }
             model.addRow(new Object[]{icon,name,address,mobile,nid});
         }
     }}}
     return model;
 }
```

This is my code that I wrote. Now I want to define a method that does all work which is mentioned above and also it will be called by another class.

Comment: You want to separate functionality (like move `makeTableModel` to another class) or you want another class to update the model?

Comment: i want another class to update the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are making a mistake in using view indices to index the model. Listeners and all methods from JTable that return row or column indices will report **view** indices (except `convertXXXIndexToModel` methods).

As the table is sorted or columns are moved around, view indices **will** differ from model indices. JTable will not sort the model or rearrange columns in the model, rather it will change its mapping to the model.

If what you have is view indices and you want to look up cell values, either

1. Use `JTable.getValueAt`, which takes view indices
2. First convert view indices to model indices using `JTable.convertRowIndexToModel` and `JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel` before indexing in the model (`JTable.getModel()`).

Your mouse listener should read:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        if( row < 0 ) return; // check if a row is selected first!
        String getvalue = table.getValueAt(row, table.convertColumnIndexToView( 4 ) ).toString(); // use table.getValueAt, this getter takes view indices! Use convertColumnIndexToView to get a view index from a model index!
        PopulatePhotographerClass pp=new PopulatePhotographerClass(getvalue);
    }
});
```

Better still would be to implement a `ListSelectionListener` to listen for selection events, rather than using a `MouseListener` to act on selection events (thanks `@mKorbel` for pointing that out). This way you would be notified directly on list selection changes.

---

If you want operations to be done from another class, write a public method in your class that extends JFrame that does this work. If you have an instance to this class in another class, simply call this newly created public method.

Suppose your JFrame class is called MyFrameWithJTable

```
public class MyFrameWithJTable extends JFrame {
    public void doSomeWork( /*parameters required in the operation*/ ) {
        // Does the work you want to call from another class
        // Eg the updates you want done in the JTable's model
    }
}
```

Then in another class, if you have an instance of the MyFrameWithJTable class you can do

```
public class AnotherClass {
    private MyFrameWithJTable instance;
    public AnotherClass( MyFrameWithJTable instance ) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    public void someMethod( ) {
        instance.doSomeWork( /*supply parameters*/ );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. `table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {` == `ListSelectionListener` with `SINGLE...`, 2. both (column and row) would be converted from view to model, 3. this answer can be missunderstood by OP, because s/he wants `"to load or refresh it from another class after a delete operation."`  == ResultSetTableModel or TableFromDatabase,

Comment: @mKorbel Euh I must be on a different plane =) I don't understand what you are saying honestly. From my understanding the MouseAdapter should now work well with regards to sorting & column reordering and indexes properly with regards to model vs view. Are you saying it isn't?

Comment: not the planes are very diff. 1. yes is possible (for tooltip, popup), but ListSelectionListener handles row (column) selection directly, and by testing if returns is more than -1 (any selection, not 1st. row) 2. sorting and filtering is about row level, hasn't something with convertColumnIndexToView in your code, both are important, 3. for why reason to compare the planes - ResultSetTableModel or TableFromDatabase (has implemented parameters as part of model), 4. anyway this answer has tree good points, not attack just to improve this answer to very good

Comment: @mKorbel IIUC he should have used a `ListSelectionListener` rather than a `MouseListener`. Good point, but I'm not writing the program for him, I'm just pointing a significant problem in his code with regards to view vs model indices. Regarding 2) the original code is using literal `4` to denote a fifth column in his **model**. In my correction I'm using `JTable.getValueAt` so this coordinate needs to be translated to view coordinates, hence the conversion using `JTable.convertColumnIndexToView`.

Comment: @mKorbel 3) *"To be on a different plane"* is an English expression that doesn't mean what you think it means =). It's not to be taken literally! 4) Thanks for pointing that out, I'll include your recommendation to use ListSelectionListener rather than a MouseListener.